# Eclipse not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, eclipse, openjdk, jre

I can't even run a simple `hello world!` program in Eclipse.

Let's go step by step. Whenever I write a program and try to save it It shows this error:

[image]

And when I try to run the program It shows this error:

[image]

I'm so confused and frustrated because I have to run programs every time through terminal `javac file.java` and `java file`.
by running `java --version` I'm getting:

```
openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

this output and eclipse version is: `19-12`

Comment: you're using Java 17, is that correct? with what version of Eclipse?

Comment: There's a bug in older versions of eclipse where it didn't work with Java 16, presumably because it was trying to convert a hex "G" into the number "16" using base16, and "G" isn't actually a hex character. "radix 16" means it's converting to int in base 16. The encoding of java version was fixed, and now it should work.

Comment: Since you have base "H" I assume it's trying to do "17", with the same error. Try a newer version of Eclipse. see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564922

Comment: please do `java --version` and find the version of your eclipse (should show in the loading screen when you first open eclipse) and add that information to your question.